# heroku, postgreSQL, django, comments, tastypie: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, tastypie, django-comments

I have a simple query on django's built in comments model and getting the error below with heroku's postgreSQL database:

```
DatabaseError: operator does not exist: integer = text LINE 1: 
... INNER JOIN "django_comments" ON ("pi ns_pin"."id" = "django_...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

After googling around it seems this error has been addressed many times before in django, but I'm still getting it (all related issues were closed 3-5 years ago) . I am using django version 1.4 and the latest build of tastypie.

The query is made under orm filters and works perfectly with my development database (sqlite3):

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):    

    comments = fields.ToManyField('my.api.api.CmntResource', 'comments', full=True, null=True)

    def build_filters(self, filters=None):
        if filters is None:
            filters = {}

        orm_filters = super(MyResource, self).build_filters(filters)

        if 'cmnts' in filters:
            orm_filters['comments__user__id__exact'] = filters['cmnts']

class CmntResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField('my.api.api.UserResource', 'user', full=True)
    site_id = fields.CharField(attribute = 'site_id')
    content_object = GenericForeignKeyField({
        My: MyResource,
    }, 'content_object')
    username = fields.CharField(attribute = 'user__username', null=True)
    user_id = fields.CharField(attribute = 'user__id', null=True)
```

Anybody have any experience with getting around this error without writing raw SQL?

Comment: Like the error says, you're trying to compare an integer to a text value. Stop doing that and the error will go away.

Comment: Incidentally, this is a good example of why testing should be done with an environment as similar as possible to where you deploy: however much a framework claims to abstract over it, something as complex as a DBMS is bound to have different behaviour and limitations.

Comment: IMSoP, yes indeed i learned that lesson today! Just changed my development DB over to PostgreSQL to work on this issue.

Comment: Wow, over 2900 views and not one up vote... I guess 2900 people found this question useless.

Comment: 5243 and counting....

Comment: i'm sorry, but i find this kinda amusing.. 14027 and counting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on IMSoP's answer:  This is a limitation of django's ORM layer when a Generic foreign key uses a text field for the object_id and the object's id field is not a text field.  Django does not want to make any assumptions or cast the object's id as something it's not.  I found an excellent article on this http://charlesleifer.com/blog/working-around-django-s-orm-to-do-interesting-things-with-gfks/.

The author of the article, Charles Leifer came up with a very cool solution for query's that are affected by this and will be very useful in dealing with this issue moving forward.

Alternatively, i managed to get my query to work as follows:

```
if 'cmnts' in filters:
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(user__id=filters['cmnts'], content_type__name = 'my',   site_id=settings.SITE_ID ).values_list('object_pk', flat=True)
    comments = [int(c) for c in comments]
    orm_filters['pk__in'] = comments
```

Originally i was searching for a way to modify the SQL similar to what Charles has done, but it turns out all i had to do was break the query out into two parts and convert the str(id)'s to int(id)'s.

Answer (score 36):

PostgreSQL is "strongly typed" - that is, every value in every query has a particular type, either defined explicitly (e.g. the type of a column in a table) or implicitly (e.g. the values input into a `WHERE` clause). All functions and operators, including `=`, have to be defined as accepting specific types - so, for instance there is an operator for `VarChar = VarChar`, and a different one for `int = int`.

In your case, you have a column which is explicitly defined as type `int`, but you are comparing it against a value which PostgreSQL has interpreted as type `text`.

SQLite, on the other hand, is "weakly typed" - values are freely treated as being of whatever type best suits the action being performed. So in your dev SQLite database the operation `'42' = 42` can be computed just fine, where PostgreSQL would need a specific definition of `VarChar = int` (or `text = int`, `text` being the type for unbounded strings in PostgreSQL).

Now, PostgreSQL will *sometimes* be helpful and automatically "cast" your values to make the types match a known operator, but more often, as the hint says, you need to do it explicitly. If you were writing the SQL yourself, an explicit type case could look like `WHERE id = CAST('42' AS INT)` (or `WHERE CAST(id AS text) = '42'`).

Since you're not, you need to ensure that the input you give to the query generator is an actual integer, not just a string which happens to consist of digits. I suspect this is as simple as using `fields.IntegerField` rather than `fields.CharField`, but I don't actually know Django, or even Python, so I thought I'd give you the background in the hope you can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the info, very well put and i do understand that is what is causing the error.  The issue is that django's gfk for the comments model uses a text field for the object_id and the object being commented on uses a an integer field..  So really the quest should have been how do i get around this without limiting the comment model to integer id's.

Answer (score 0):

To do not hack you ORM and external software postgres allow you register your own casts and compare operations. [Please look example in similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773805/postgresql-enum-and-character-varying-updating/43748427#43748427).