# postgresql: enum and character varying, updating

Tags: postgresql, enums

I have the ENUM type in postgresql

```sql
CREATE TYPE user_state AS ENUM ('unconfirmed', 'locked', 'active');
```

I have a field `state` in table `users` with the type `user_state`.

And I try to execute the next query:

```sql
UPDATE "users" SET "state" = 'active'::character varying WHERE "id" = 1 (*1)
```

But the query fails. The error is: `Column "state" is of type user_state but expression is of type character varying. Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

Okay, there were a little bit of reading mans, a writing a little bit of code, and I have implicit type cast for character varying to user_state:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    character_varying_to_user_status(user_state)
    RETURNS user_state AS $$
    SELECT $1::user_state
    $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE CAST (character varying AS user_state)
    WITH FUNCTION character_varying_to_user_status (character varying)
    AS IMPLICIT
```

But this does not work. It works only in case if id does not exist (so, query does nothing, so, syntax and type checking are correct now I suppose). But if id exists, postgresql says me that stack is overflowed (that is why I'm on this site now, ha-ha). The error is:

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "character_varying_to_user_status" during inlining
SQL function "character_varying_to_user_status" during startup
SQL function "character_varying_to_user_status" statement 1
SQL function "character_varying_to_user_status" statement 1
SQL function "character_varying_to_user_status" statement 1
...
...
SQL function "character_varying_to_user_status" statement 1

In operator:
UPDATE "users" SET "state" = 'unconfirmed'::character varying WHERE "id" = 8
```

And I have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Postgresql 9.1 and lift-squeryl-record (of version 2.5).

(*1) The query `UPDATE "users" SET "state" = 'active'::character varying WHERE "id" = 1` is not a real one. I use squeryl (scala-language orm), and the squeryl generates the query, so, I can't just remove `::character varying` to have it work. Real query looks like this (in error answer): `update "users" set "state" = ? where "id" = ? jdbcParams:[active,10]` and answers to me exactly as I wrote in question above (about rewrite or cast the expression). So, the query is given `as is` and I cant change it: I can't just remove ::character varying or add ::user_state or CAST(.. as ..).

UPD. Could also somebody try run code on a newer version of postgresql (9.2, 9.3, 9.4)? If it works, it is the answer too.

Comment: could also be caused by not having cast from enum to varchar!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with a simple attempt is you have a cast calling the cast, calling the cast, calling the cast...

You need somehow to get away from varchar->enum in your cast. Simplest (most understandable) way is to just manually convert. Note the string literals being cast in the case statement aren't text they are quoted-unknown-type which sidesteps the infinite recursion.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TYPE t_tl AS ENUM ('red', 'amber', 'green');

CREATE FUNCTION dummy_cast(varchar) RETURNS t_tl AS $$
    SELECT CASE $1
        WHEN 'red' THEN 'red'::t_tl
        WHEN 'amber' THEN 'amber'::t_tl
        WHEN 'green' THEN 'green'::t_tl
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE CAST (varchar AS t_tl) WITH FUNCTION dummy_cast(varchar) AS ASSIGNMENT;

CREATE TABLE t (x t_tl);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('red');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('green'::varchar);

SELECT * FROM t;

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: It works, nice peace of code, thank you very much. The idea about CASE looks simple, I feel myself little stupid, only the excuse for me is that i'm not familar with postgresql :). Thanks again.

Comment: hm-hm, on other hand I didnt know about quoted-unknown-type , so, may be I was not able to solve it myself...

Comment: @Richard Huxton Thank you 4 sharing this with us. I like it very much. Upvote for CASE.

Answer (score 4):

Very late to the party here, but I would like to add that in this specific case it is enough to simply cast the `varchar` to `text` to prevent recursion.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dummy_cast(varchar) RETURNS t_tl AS $$
    SELECT ('' || $1)::t_tl;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may register equal operator *instead of* define `cast` one. I did it for `Java` + `MyBatis` in similar situation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION type_user_state_with_text_equals(_a user_state, _b text)
    RETURNS boolean AS
    $func$
        SELECT _a = _b::user_state;
    $func$
    LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OPERATOR = (
    leftarg = user_state,
    rightarg = text,
    procedure = type_user_state_with_text_equals,
    COMMUTATOR = =,
    NEGATOR = !=,
    HASHES, MERGES
);
```

You may read about postgres [user-defined operations in documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xoper.html) and do not forget look at [optimization hints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xoper-optimization.html).