# Django and Postgresql operator does not exist: integer = character varying

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have these two models:

```
class CachedRecord(models.Model):
    recordname = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    recordcount = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.recordname

class CachedRecordData(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(CachedRecord)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.data
```

When I try to delete a CachedRecord from the admin panel I get this errror:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/myapp/cachedrecord/

operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...ON ( "myapp_cachedrecorddata"."record_id" = "myapp...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have found many questions (so this might be a duplicate), but I really don't understand any answer.

[heroku, postgreSQL, django, comments, tastypie: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044754/heroku-postgresql-django-comments-tastypie-no-operator-matches-the-given-na)

[No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. -- Netbeans, Postgresql 8.4 and Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739808/no-operator-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types-you-might-need-to-add-e)

Where would I need to add these castings in django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set a character field (`recordname`) as the primary key for `CachedRecord`.

Django created an automatic primary key (of type integer) for `CachedRecordData` called `id` - since there is no primary key specified in the model definition.

Now when you try to delete `CachedRecord`, django is creating a primary key lookup to make sure all related `CachedRecordData` instances are deleted, and since one key is a character and the other an integer - the database is giving this error.

The easiest way to solve this problem is remove `primary_key=True` from `recordname` and let django manage the keys correctly. You can always add an index on that column, or other constraints (for example, set `unique=True`).

You also have a similar problem here:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.recordname+":"+self.recordcount
```

You are adding a string `':'` with `self.recordcount` which will result in a `TypeError` exception, as you cannot combine a string with a number:

```
>>> ':'+3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

To solve this issue:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{}:{}'.format(self.recordname, self.recordcount)
```

Comment: so i cannot have a string primary key?

Answer (score 11):

*Been a couple of years since this question was asked/answered but I hit on the same issue today and found the accepted answer, while "easy" didn't really address the underlying issue with unexpected database table types. Django is built to "manage the keys correctly" for user defined primary keys just fine.*

I hit a similar issue with a message of `ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character = uuid`.

I hit this issue after migrating my Django project's MySQL database to PostgreSQL. MySQL doesn't have a native UUID field so it represents the `models.UUIDField` with a `VARCHAR(32)`. After the migration the field type in PostgreSQL was also created as a `character(32)`. In order to resolve the issue I had to alter the field type using the PostgreSQL command line:

`ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_field TYPE uuid USING uuid::uuid;`

This casts the field type into the native UUID type for PostgreSQL that Django expected to find.

I'm guessing the OP added the `recordname` field after the `CachedRecord` table already had to `CachedRecordData` using the integer ID field that Django creates by default if primary_key isn't defined. After adding the new `recordname` field as the primary key the OP needed to update the existing relationships to use the new primary key.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution for you. I completely understand and respect what the others are saying here about using an Integer field as the primary key, and by default this is indeed what Django does. As a result, if changing the structure of your database is a possible option then please do that first!!

But if you're like me and end up with a problem like this and using Django's defaults just aren't an option for you, I changed my primary key's field type. Whilst originally I had:

```
Username = models.CharField(max_length=1024, primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

Change this to a TextField instead!

```
Username = models.TextField(max_length=1024, primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

This fixed it for me, I'm guessing maybe it's a bug with the way Django tries to structure / index a charfield as a primary key? I'm not sure.

Hope that helps!