# postgresql: Converting bytea to bigint

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, postgresql-9.1

I have to convert a bytea entry for a query to bigint. How could this be done?

**More Info:**

I have a hibernate repository as below -

```
 @Query(value = "update Sample_Table set other_id = ?1 where id = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
 void saveOrUpdateOtherId(Long other_id, Long id);
```

Hibernate somehow taking `id` (in where clause) as `bytea` and since '*Sample_Table*' has this id field as `bigint` and thus it throws type mismatch problem.

I have tried using CAST to convert `bytea` to `bigint` but it didn't succeed and error msg says `bytea` can not be casted to `bigint`.

How can i change `bytea` to `bigint`?

---

**Edit:**

Sample_Table DAO:

```
@Table(name = "Sample_Table")
public class Sample{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "other_id")
    private Long other_id;
}
```

`id` field is defined in here as Long.

---

**Edit-2**
If someone get such issue, most likely he is passing null value in the query.

Comment: You should provide your Sample_Table class as well. Usually it is because you defined the `id` not in a proper way.

Comment: 'id' field is defined here as Long (bigint). Not sure, why 8 bit big int is interpreted as byte array here.

Comment: upgrade postgres to 9.4 not an option?

Comment: When you've verified your table *is* using `bigint`, I'd highly suspect Spring's mapping your Long in a crazy way. Are you sure you're passing a `Long` into that `saveOrUpdateOtherId` function? Have you tried a non-native query and does it fail in the same way?

Comment: System up gradation request and its actual implementation will take atleast a week time. Still, it is not clear that it is postgres issue that got fixed in latest version.

Comment: Have looked into similar SO posts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044754/heroku-postgresql-django-comments-tastypie-no-operator-matches-the-given-na and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739808/no-operator-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types-you-might-need-to-add-e

They possibly have corrected this problem via tweaking their query. But my query is very simple and dont know if repo query require some alteration.

Comment: @mabi - I have verified that i am passing a long value. I have not tried non-native query yet. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 7):

I was running into this issue for a repository query which inserts a record which has a nullable column. When the value for that column is null, hibernate uses the wrong type and I would see exceptions like this from Postgres:

```
cannot cast type bytea to bigint
```

Eventually found this blog post with a solution: http://www.carbonrider.com/2020/08/15/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-cannot-cast-type-bytea-to-uuid/
which is to use Hibernate's `TypedParameterValue`.
Copy and pasting their snippets:

```
@Query("select * from user where firstname=:name and id=:id", nativeQuery=true)
public List<user> findByNameAndId(@Param("name") String firstName, @Param("id")TypedParameterValue id);
```

```
UUID userId = ... //Retrived from request parameter.
TypedParameterValue userIdParam = new TypedParameterValue(new PostgresUUIDType(), userId);
userRepository.findByNameAndId(userName, userIdParam);
```

Not ideal to have a Hibernate-specific solution rather than a purely JPA one, but ‍♂️. Big thanks to "Carbon Rider" or whoever added that post!

Comment: See also > CAST(CAST(?1 AS TEXT) AS BIGINT) > https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321877/1503636

Comment: for other types one can use StandardBasicTypes class to specify types.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward function to cast from bytea (a chunk of memory) to a base datatype, other than passing through the bit datatype from a properly padded hexadecimal string:

```
SELECT ('x'||lpad(encode('\001'::bytea, 'hex'), 16, '0'))::bit(64)::bigint
```

Or, if your bytea is already 8 bytes and your Postgres installation runs with the default setting `bytea_output = 'hex'`, [cast to text and remove the leading backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56008861/3886053) instead:

```
SELECT right(bytea_val::text, -1)::bit(64)::bigint
FROM (SELECT '\x0000000000000001'::bytea as bytea_val) x
```

Answer (score 3):

The following expression worked for me, to convert from `bytes::bytea` to a `bigint`:

```
get_byte(bytes, 0)::bigint << 8
    | get_byte(bytes, 1) << 8
    | get_byte(bytes, 2) << 8
    | get_byte(bytes, 3) << 8
    | get_byte(bytes, 4) << 8
    | get_byte(bytes, 5) << 8
    | get_byte(bytes, 6) << 8
    | get_byte(bytes, 7)
```

This correctly handles the sign bit as well.

Comment: Could you add an example of using?

Comment: The code fails when I pass `E'\\x100000'`.

Answer (score 2):

One of your parameters is `null` which cannot be turned into a `bigint`.

Answer (score 1):

As Jan Nielsen said

One of your parameters is null which cannot be turned into a bigint.

You are trying to pass null in the query.