# Spring data repository sends null as bytea to PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

After switching from MySQL to **PostgreSQL** I found out that my SQL query (@Query in spring data repository interface) does not work anymore. The issue is caused by **null** value being sent as **bytea** and I'm getting following exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Repository with @Query:

```
public interface WineRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Wine, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM WINE w WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR w.id = ?1)", nativeQuery = true)
    Wine simpleTest(Long id);
}
```

Simple test:

```
LOGGER.warn("test1: {}", wineRepository.simpleTest(1L));    //ok
LOGGER.warn("test2: {}", wineRepository.simpleTest(null));  //PSQLException
```

In the real case I have multiple parameters which can be null and I would prefer not checking them in java code but sending them to sql query. I have checked questions here on stackoverflow but found none with a good answer especially for spring data repository @query annotation.

**What is a correct way of handling null values with PostgreSQL? Or do you have any hints how to fix my approach?** Thanks!

**Update:**
Issue seems to be related to `nativeQuery = true`, when value is false, null values work as expected. So the question is whether it is possible to make it function even with nativeQuery enabled.

Answer (score 11):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM WINE w
WHERE ?1 IS NULL OR w.id = CAST(CAST(?1 AS TEXT) AS BIGINT)
```

It satisfies the type checker and should have the same properties as the original query. `CAST` is not a big performance hit if it happens on a constant value rather than a value from a database row.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check whether a Java `null` is equal to Postgres `NULL` which I think is not necessary. You can rewrite as following and avoid sending null to the `simpleTest` function at all.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM WINE w WHERE (w.id IS NULL OR w.id = ?1)", nativeQuery = true)
Wine simpleTest(Long id);
```

Comment: But my intention is to check whether input from Java is null. I am not trying to select values from database which are null.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in an @Query where a Long was being interpreted by Postgres as a bytea. The solution for me was to unbox the @Param...by passing a long value, Postgres correctly interpreted the value as a bigint

Comment: In addition to this reply we converted the Long into a primitive. If the Long object was null, we initialized the primitive with -1 and checked the -1 in the sql query (:modelId = -1 OR table.model_id = :modelId)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old issue, but you should be able to fix that bay casting the java value. Something like:

```
public interface WineRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Wine, Long> {
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM WINE w WHERE (?1\\:\\:bigint IS NULL OR w.id = ?1\\:\\:bigint)", nativeQuery = true)
Wine simpleTest(Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue as you are. After I researched this problem i found the answer on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2370

The problem will be solved by using Spring Data JPA 2.7. You can find the source code to demonstrate this at https://github.com/heowc-scratch/hibernate_postgres_HHH-14778/tree/main.

maybe it's helpful